# Get JavaScript alert in case of specific words on web page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, alert, screen-scraping

Is it possible to get a JavaScript alert when there is a given word (or words) on a currently visited web page?
I have searched in all the Google extensions, but I haven't found it unfortunately.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Go here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija , delete this question by yourself, find out how to use the extension to do what you wanna do, come back with specific questions, if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an extension for you. Just download and unzip the file then follow these [instructions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#manifest) to install. (The load unpacked part)

**Instructions for the plugin:**

To change the words which it alerts for. You click on the details button in the extensions page and scroll down and click the Extension options button. You can also click the Extension icon in the web bar and click Options.

hopefully, this helps.

[link to download on github](https://github.com/anbcodes/AlertForWords/releases/tag/v1.0.0)

Comment: Wauw thanks a lot! Unfortunately, I get the error "package invalid crx required proof missing" while dragging in the the extensions page.

Comment: I added a link to a zip file that should work if you unzip it then follow the instructions on how to load it.

Comment: You are really fantastic!! Thank you so much for doing this!!
I have a last wish, a field in the options which can be used to set a timer before it checks for the words. For example: after 3000 ms should it look for the given words. The other JavaScripts on the website shouldn't be affected by this timer. If I need to donate, please let me know.

Comment: @franky555 I added that feature for you and moved my code onto GitHub.

Comment: Thanks again! It **seems** like it is looking for the words, found one of them, waits the given milliseconds and give an alert. 
I'm afraid it doesn't let the website load, then wait the given milliseconds, only then look for the words and give an alert. Is that true?
Thank you again!

Comment: @franky555 Yes, it gets all the words on the website before the wait. I can change that if you want me to.

Comment: I would love to see you change that, so it loads the website completely, waits x seconds, then look for the words and alerts. Thank you so much!

Comment: @franky555 added the releases to github

Comment: I tried to edit you script. I would like to enter a regular expression instead one or more words. It didn't work. What do I have to change in the index.js?

Comment: I can pay if you need?

Comment: @franky555 published version 1.1.0 which includes regex

Comment: thank you again very much, I will try if I can use it!

Answer (score -1):

With help from stackoverflow I have found a script that works:

```
if ((document.documentElement.textContent || document.documentElement.innerText).indexOf('cows') > -1)
{
      alert("Hello");
}
```

The only problem is: it works only once. After saving the JS code, the current page refreshes and it works. But when I reload the page manually, the JS code isn't executed. BTW; I'm using the extentions "Custom Javascript for Websites 2"